# MySQL: Limiting result for WHERE IN list

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say there are millions of records in my_table.

Here is my query to extract rows with a specific name from list:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Name IN ('name1','name2','name3','name4')
```

How do I limit the returned result per name1, name2, etc?
The following query would limit the whole result (to 100).

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Name IN ('name1','name2','name3','name4') LIMIT 100
```

I need to limit to 100 for each name.

Comment: To limit 100 per name you will have to write 4 (sub) queries which each return 100 results.

Comment: There is a way to do this without four subqueries using `RANK()`, which MySQL doesn't support unfortunately. Gordon Linoff's answer seems to simulate the ranking functionality.

Comment: I know cross apply! oh wait mySQL..

Comment: Norbert: I tried to use subqueries with lim in each... but that increased response time... And "WHERE Name IN" is faster than subqueries...

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a pain in MySQL, but the best method is probably variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@n = name, @rn + 1,
                        if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from my_table t cross join
           (select @n := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by name
     ) t
where rn <= 100;
```

If you want to limit this to a subset of the names, then add the `where` clause to the subquery.

Note:  If you want to pick certain rows -- such as the oldest or newest or biggest or tallest -- just add a second key to the `order by` in the subquery.

Comment: I started writing an answer using `RANK` until I noticed the MySQL tag and was sad. Tested your query in sqlfiddle and it seems to work. Nice solution.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ee5aa/1

Comment: Gordon: thank you, but name1, name2, etc is a list I invented to simplify the problem. Your function is tightened to nameN format... My real list is like that: 1) 400 Zone-Mainline.PLC.Prgm_Zone01.Zone01_LineCycleTime_Hist_x.Zone01_LineCycleTime_Hist_00; 2) 300 Zone-CoverSub.PLC.Prgm_Zone01.Zone01_LineCycleTime_Hist_x.Zone01_LineCycleTime_Hist_00; etc

Comment: @ihtus . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you asked, which this does.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, providing proper sample data and an explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE Name IN ('name1','name2','name3','name4') FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY

Comment: This fetches 100 rows total, not 100 rows per *name*.

Comment: `fetch` is not a valid MySQL keyword.